# Slow processing from converting List of ExpandoObject to a DataTable with conditions

Tags: c#, list, datatable, expandoobject

I am working on exporting a Data Grid from Dev Express with a large dataset to excel on the server because they do not provide a method. They only provide client side export.

I am working with:

Records: 68,170 rows and 27 Columns.

I am also taking into account the columns they have showing on the grid as well as the filters they are applying. Therefore, I only need to add the columns that are visible from the Data Grid

The way we are loading the data grid is based on ad-hoc queries via a data table call. (this is working fine and is not an issue on speed)

Here are the steps we are working with

1. Get the raw data from the database via a SQL query and data table (speed is fine -> not an issue)
2. Convert the raw data that is in a data table and convert it to List of dynamic objects with the `ExpandoObject` object (speed is fine -> not an issue) (we need to do this so we can filter out the data that is passed in via the grid with Dev Express data grid filter etc.)
3. We then pass the filter and now `IEnumerable` list to the `DataSourceLoader` via Dev Express: [DataSourceLoader](https://devexpress.github.io/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data/net/api/DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.DataSourceLoader.html) (speed is fine -> not an issue)
4. After research and finding out we need to have a `DataTable` to use DevExpress Spreadsheet control `.Import()` call [WorksheetExtensions.Import()](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Spreadsheet.WorksheetExtensions.Import(Worksheet--DataTable--Boolean--Int32--Int32--DataImportOptions)), I'm trying to convert our `List` of `ExpandoObjects` to a `DataTable` (this is VERY SLOW!)
5. Pass the newly created `DataTable` to the Dev Express Spreadsheet control to create a byte array so it can be passed back to the client for download to the end user via Excel!

Steps 1 to 3 and 5 are NOT an issue and I just add them for understanding.

**Step 4 is the problem!**

I am looking for a faster method to convert the `List` of `ExpandoObjects` to a `DataTable`. Grant it, I am cycling 1,840,590 times and with having code commented out that could impact the speed, it still takes awhile!

Any ideas of how to speed up this setup?

```
    private DataTable ExportOnServerListExpandoObjectToDataTable(List<ExpandoObject> list, IList<ExportOnServerColumnInfoModel> columnsInfo)
    #pragma warning restore CA1822 // Mark members as static
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start in ExportOnServerListExpandoObjectToDataTable: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

        var visibleColumns = columnsInfo.Where(w => w.Visible == true).ToList();

        // build columns based on the visible columns that are selected and displaying on the grid.
        var dataTable = new DataTable("dt");

        foreach (var createColumns in visibleColumns)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(createColumns.DataField, typeof(string)));
        }

        // add rows
        foreach (var row in list)
        {
            /*var data = dataTable.NewRow();*/

            /*IDictionary<string, object> propertyValues = row;*/

            foreach (var column in visibleColumns)
            {
                /*object value;
                bool hasValue = propertyValues.TryGetValue(column.DataField, out value);*/
                object value = "titus";
                if (value == null)
                {
                    // data[column.DataField] = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    // data[column.DataField] = value;
                }
            }

            /*dataTable.Rows.Add(data);*/

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("index: " + list.IndexOf(row) + "Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("End in ExportOnServerListExpandoObjectToDataTable: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Using C#, VS 2022

Comment: So you want a datatable, and you already did have one in step 2..

Comment: it's probably worth noting that data manipulation is a database's bread and butter- if you know the filter conditions you should tell the database to use them to remove the data you don't want rather than burning resources downloading data you'll throw away

Comment: @CaiusJard: yes, I needed to filter the data. That datatable was the raw data. Answered posted.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seemed to be with `Debug.WriteLine(...)`.

I thought I had removed all my `Debug.WriteLine(...)`s, but did not.

This line was the culprit.

```
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("index: " + list.IndexOf(row) + "Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

I had the `Debug.WriteLine(...)` so I could see what the values were, but in the end it was actually the issue.

I hope this helps someone else in time!